# C# Converter DataSet em JSON

Tags: c#, json, dataset

Preciso converter um DataSet em um JSON para poder recuperar na View. A query aí é só um exemplo, pois é uma consulta grande. Vi em alguns lugares coisas como:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
```

Mas não funcionou...

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx"))
    {
       string query = select * from teste;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {

                sda.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
        return ???
    }
}
```

Comment: O que não deu certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma suposição sem saber o retorno fica complicado dizer, mas, vamos supor em um exemplo minimo que esse `select` (`SELECT * FROM teste;`) retorne dois campos, o campo `Id` e o campo `Nome` e um outro ponto a observar é não precisa utilizar `SqlDataAdapter` para retornar os dados dessa `SQL`, ***exemplo simples***:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        string query = "SELECT id, nome FROM teste;";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            ds.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "teste");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
        .SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);

    var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject(json, (new [] { new { id = 0, nome = "" } }).GetType());

    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

nesse exemplo existe duas conversões que é da tabela para um texto no formato `json` depois para o objeto desse `json` e depois o retorno pelo seu `action` do `controller` talvez isso se torne inviável para dados muito grandes, então, esse exemplo poderia ser modificado para o logo abaixo que tem um lógica melhor e o desempenho superior:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{       
    List<object> listas = new List<object>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        string query = "SELECT id, nome FROM teste;";
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                listas.Add(new { id = reader.GetInt32(0), nome = reader.GetString(1) });
            }
        }
    }            
    return Json(listas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

<sub>***Observação:***</sub>

- na linha `listas.Add(new { id = reader.GetInt32(0), nome = reader.GetString(1) });` são os campos que viram no resultado, se tiver mais deve ser adicionado nesse `objeto`.
- para ser convertido para ações do `MVC` deve utilizar `Json` e também o segundo paramento para liberar as requisições do tipo `GET` (`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`).
- essa forma não utiliza `DataSet`, porque, não há necessidade.

Comment: De fato ficou meio solto sem a string, mas veja se ajuda a entender melhor, a query retorna um dataset com 3 Tables, o que eu preciso está na Table[2], essa por sua vez possui os campos admAtribuido e quantidade_admAtribuido....

Comment: @CaioVinícius é o primeiro exemplo então, aonde está isso: `.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);` coloque `.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[3]);` e
`(new [] { new { admAtribuido  = "", quantidade_admAtribuido= 0} }).GetType()` ??? consegiu ver ai? tem uma coisa importante admAtribuido é texto?

Comment: Seguindo a primeira resposta do @Virgilio Novic eu consegui, apenas tive que trocar essa parte:


using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            ds.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "teste");
            con.Close();
        }

pela que estava usando:

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {

                sda.Fill(ds);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo onde uso dois *TableAdapters* em 1 *DataSet*

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string customerCommandText = "select * from customers";
    SqlDataAdapter customerAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(customerCommandText, connection);

    string ordersCommandText = "select * from Orders";
    SqlDataAdapter ordersAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(ordersCommandText, connection);

    DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet();
    customerAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Customers");
    ordersAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Orders");

    DataRelation relation = customerOrders.Relations.Add("CustomerOrders",
        customerOrders.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerId"],
        customerOrders.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerId"]);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerOrders, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

DDL das tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] (
    [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Valor] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customers] PRIMARY KEY ([CustomerId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Teste] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Orders] PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
)
```

DataSet serializado

```
{
  "Customers": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 1,
      "Valor": 920.00
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 2,
      "Valor": 930.00
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 3,
      "Valor": 932.00
    }
  ],
  "Orders": [
    {
      "OrderId": 1,
      "CustomerId": 1,
      "Teste": "636510290829216964"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 2,
      "CustomerId": 1,
      "Teste": "636510290829216964"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 3,
      "CustomerId": 1,
      "Teste": "636510290829216964"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 4,
      "CustomerId": 2,
      "Teste": "636510290839303071"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 5,
      "CustomerId": 2,
      "Teste": "636510290839303071"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 6,
      "CustomerId": 2,
      "Teste": "636510290839303071"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 7,
      "CustomerId": 3,
      "Teste": "636510290849322161"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 8,
      "CustomerId": 3,
      "Teste": "636510290849322161"
    },
    {
      "OrderId": 9,
      "CustomerId": 3,
      "Teste": "636510290849322161"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Acredito que sua solução não tenha servido porque não dei detalhes mais claros sobre o resultado da query, mas obrigado assim mesmo....